# Using MYSQL, SELECT every nth row from a subquery SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table of over 300,000 rows and I would like to render this data on a graph, but 300,000 rows isn't really necessary all at once. For example, even though there may be 100 rows of data for a given day, I don't need to display all that data if I'm showing a whole year worth of data. So I would like to "granularize" the data.

I was thinking of getting everything and then using a script to remove what I don't need, but that seems like it would be much slower and harder on the database.

So here's what I have so far.

```
SET @row_number := 0;
  SELECT @row_number := @row_number + 1 as row_number, 
  price, region, timestamp as row_number FROM pricehistory;
```

This gives me all the rows and numbers them. I was planning on adding a where clause to get every 1000 rows (i.e. every nth row) like this

```
SET @row_number := 0;
SELECT @row_number := @row_number + 1 as row_number, 
  price, region, timestamp as row_number FROM pricehistory 
  WHERE row_number % 1000 = 0;
```

But MYSQL doesn't see `row_number` as a column for some reason. Any ideas? I've looked at other solutions online, but they don't seem to work for MYSQL in particular.

Comment: Do the rows have a unique ID?

Comment: Don't bother with adding a calculated column. If the ID is sequential, simply use it instead. It won't be as accurate, but that doesn't seem to be important in your case and the good news is that it will be much faster. Another way is to use a subquery with `LIMIT x, 1000` to give you the intervals.

Comment: You cannot use aliases from SELECT clauses in the WHERE clauses; those result fields basically do not exist until after the WHERE is applied against the raw FROM results. The only way this will not be "harder" on the database is that it sends less results; otherwise it is more taxing query when it works. _You also cannot use the same alias twice in a SELECT._

Comment: @Uueerdo Ok, so then technically `"@row_number := @row_number + 1" % 1000 = 0` would be recognized?

Comment: @RacilHilan I probably will end up doing that. Especially if it's faster.

Comment: Your quotes confuse me, but It is best not to use session/@ variables outside of SELECT expressions (I.e. not in FROM, not in WHERE, not in ORDER BY, etc...)

Comment: @Uueerdo It's the name MYSQL gives to the column https://i.imgur.com/YtK3DnK.png

Comment: @david2278 ah, that is because it was not aliased in that query.

Answer (score 0):

As Racil's comment suggested, you can just go by an auto-incremented id field if you have one; but you've stated the amount of data for different dates could be different, so this could make for a very distorted graph. If you select every 1000th record for a year and half the rows are from the last 3 months ("holiday shopping" for a commerce example), the latter half of a year graph will actually reflect the latter quarter of the year. For more useful results you're most likely better off with something like this:

```
SELECT region, DATE(timestamp) AS theDate
    , AVG(price), MIN(price), MAX(price)
FROM pricehistory
GROUP BY region, theDate
;
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like I'm going to get another answer so I'll go ahead and write the solution I came up with.

My data is pretty evenly distributed as it grabs prices at regular intervals so there's no reason to worry about that.

Here's my solution.

Let's say I have 500,000 rows and I want to display a subset of those rows let's say 5000 rows. 500000/5000 is 100 so I take 100 and use it in my select statement like this `SELECT * FROM pricehistory where id % 100 = 0;`

Here is the actual code

`public function getScaleFactor($startDate, $endDate) {
        $numPricePoints = $this->getNumPricePointsBetweenDates($startDate, $endDate);
        $scaleFactor = 1;
        if ($numPricePoints > $this->desiredNumPricePoints) {
            $scaleFactor = floor($numPricePoints / $this->desiredNumPricePoints);
        }
         return $scaleFactor;
    }`

I then use `$scaleFactor` in the SQL like this `SELECT * FROM pricehistory WHERE id % {$scaleFactor} = 0;`

This isn't a perfect solution because you don't always end up with 5000 rows exactly, but I don't NEED exactly 5000 rows. I'm just trying to reduce the resolution of the data while still getting a graph that looks close to what it would be had I used all 500,000 rows.